# input 2dimensional strings and print

Tags: python, python-3.x

> My question:

```
maze = [list(map(int, input())) for _ in range(4)]
print(maze)
```

input:

```
101111
101010
101011
111011
```

output:

`[[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]]`

I thought that the output is

`[[101111], [11010], [101011], [111011]]`

because in python when we use input function, we get string. So the string converts to int by int() function(in map).
Why is it not the output?

Comment: `map` iterates the iterable, in this case `input()` so each character separately is converted to an `int`. If you want the whole string as int just do `maze = [int(input()) for _ in range(4)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map()` takes your input, e.g. `"101111"` and iterates over it character by character, converting it to an `int`, i.e. running the function `int("1")`, `int("0")` and so forth. At the end you have 6 integers `1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1`.

`list()` then converts this into a list, so you got `[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

This will be done 4 times because of the for loop. The end result is a list of lists with single digit ints.

To achieve an output like `[1001, 1110]`, you can leave out `list` and `map` as suggested by [Tomerikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045800/tomerikoo):

```py
maze = [int(input()) for _ in range(4)]
```

Not sure if you actually wanted that, but if each of the elements in that list shall be wrapped in their own list `[[1001], [1110]]`, put a list around it:

```py
maze = [[int(input())] for _ in range(4)]
```